# AMPscript Attribute from Contact Model

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have searched the documentation with no luck.

In an email, I want to use a value that is from an attribute that has been configured through Attribute Groups within the Contact Builder Data Designer.

Is there a way within AMPscript to get this value easily?

Example:

Attribute Group Name: `Contact_Details`, This group has a field called `Gender`.
The attribute group is linked to a Data Extension Called `Contact_Details`.

What is the easiest way to get this `Gender` field via AMPscript? I know I can do a lookup but wanting to see if by using an Attribute I don't have to do this.

Thanks!